# Dr. Racket GUI not working properly

Tags: thirdpartyapps

DrRacket (both 6.8 and 6.9) when installed has issues with GUI. Racket developers suggest that the problem could be in the os side. I have attached the screen shot. The same kind of problem is for other windows in Racket IDE.

I tried changing the file GTK_CSD=1  in the file /etc/profile.d/gtk-csd.sh to GTK_CSD="" but it did not work.

[image: DrRacket Startup Window]

Answer (score 1):

So, I ran into this issue recently and found a decent workaround that fixes this. It is caused due to the GTK client side decorations. Hence, we can disable it temporarily for DrRacket.

- After installing DrRacket, open the startup script

  - In my case, I installed at `/usr/bin/drracket`
  - In **your case**, you would need to edit `~/racket/bin/drracket`
- `vi /usr/bin/drracket` (or) `vi ~/racket/bin/drracket`
- Add this line at the head of the script

```
# Workaround to remove client side decoration
GTK_CSD=""
```

- Save and exit. Now, open DrRacket and it should work fine.

Comment: This solution also still works with DrRacket 7.8. It is not a permanent solution of course, but it makes the dialogs (such as language choice) usable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why did you used an sh package and not the PPA available who can work with the package manager you have

Just use apt

[image: DrRacket PPA]

https://download.racket-lang.org/

https://launchpad.net/~plt/+archive/ubuntu/racket

---

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plt/racket`

`sudo apt install racket`

[image: DrRacket Main Window]